# How can I check if an element is within another one in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any direct way in JavaScript or jQuery to check if an element is within another one.

I'm not referring to the `$(this).parent` as the element I wish to find can be a random number steps lower in the tree of elements.

As an example, I would like to check if `< div id="THIS DIV">` would be within `< div id="THIS PARENT">`:

```
<div id="THIS_PARENT">
 <div id="random">
  <div id="random">
   <div id="random">
    <div id="THIS_DIV">
(... close all divs ...)
```

So in pseudo code:

```
 if($("div#THIS_DIV").isWithin("div#THIS_PARENT")) ...
```

If there isn't any direct way I'll probably do a function for this but still it's worth asking.

Comment: You can use build in function `jQuery.contains( container, descendant )`. See my answer below.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You could do this:

```
if($('#THIS_DIV','#THIS_PARENT').length == 1) {

}
```

By [specifying a context](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/jQuery#expressioncontext) for the search (the second argument) we are basically saying "look for an element with an ID of `#THIS_DIV` within an element with ID of `#THIS_PARENT`". This is the most succint way of doing it using jQuery.

We could also write it like this, using [`find`](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/find), if it makes more sense to you:

```
if($('#THIS_PARENT').find('#THIS_DIV').length == 1) {

}
```

Or like this, using [`parents`](http://docs.jquery.com/API/1.2/Traversing/parents), if you want to search from the child upwards:

```
if($('#THIS_DIV').parents('#THIS_PARENT').length == 1) {

}
```

Any of these should work fine. The `length` bit is necessary to make sure the length of the "search" is > 0. I would of course personally recommend you go with the first one as it's the simplest.

Also, if you are referring to an element by ID it's not necessary (although of course perfectly okay) to preface the selector with the tag name. As far as speed, though, it doesn't really help as jQuery is going to use the native `getElementById()` internally. Using the tag name is only important when selecting by class, as `div.myclass` is much, much faster than `.myclass` if only `<div>` elements are going to have the particular class.

Comment: Because I managed to get here by searching "javascript", here's a way to do it the same as the `parent()` version using the Prototype library:  `if ($('THIS_DIV').up('#THIS_PARENT')) {..}`

Comment: I would like to add if you have 2 matching parents, this answer will return `false`, to avoid it you can remove `==1`, so you will get this: `if($('#THIS_DIV').parents('.CLASS_PARENT').length){...}` its going to return 0 (`false`) if there are no results and `true` if there are 1, or more results.

Answer (score 23):

With jQuery >=1.4 (2010) you can use the very fast function [jQuery.contains()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.contains/)

This static method works with DOM elements, not with jQuery elements and returns `true` or `false`.

```
jQuery.contains( container, descendant )
```

Example: To check if a element is in the document you could do this:

```
jQuery.contains( document.body, myElement )
```