# Best way to find out if element is a descendant of another

Tags: jquery

I am in the process of implementing jQuery, and taking out Prototype libraries in my codebase, and I am wondering if you could give me the best way to implement this functionality in jQuery.
I am familiar with the jQuery ancestor`>`descendant syntax, but just want to check if an element is a descendant by true of false, like the code below:
can someone give me the most efficient jQuery solution for this ?

```
<div id="australopithecus">
  <div id="homo-herectus">
    <div id="homo-sapiens"></div>
  </div>
</div>

$('homo-sapiens').descendantOf('australopithecus');
// -> true

$('homo-herectus').descendantOf('homo-sapiens');
// -> false
```

Comment: dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/865486/how-can-i-check-if-an-element-is-within-another-one-in-jquery/865551

Comment: Use `jQuery.contains()`. See my answer below.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I would think you could take advantage of CSS style selection here, with returned length..

```
$('#australopithecus #homo-sapiens').length // Should be 1
$('#homo-sapiens #homo-herectus').length // Should be 0
```

Not exactly true/false, but checking 0/1 as a boolean should work. :)

Alternately, you could do something like $('#parent').find('#child') and check the length there.

Comment: thanks for all the good answers!! i didn't realize i had so many options :)

Comment: Thank you! And you can "cast" these to `true`/`false` by prepending `!!`, like `!!$('#australopithecus #homo-sapiens').length`, which returns `true`.

Comment: There is no need to cast these to anything else since in javascript false, 0, null and NaN are all counted as false when used in if statements ...

Comment: If you really want to get technical, it's more that those values are coerced to truthy or falsy values in comparisons. It's not really specifically in `if` statements or other conditionals.

For example, if you were doing a strict comparison to `true`, you'd want to use the `!!` to coerce it youself into a proper boolean value.

That being said, it's rare that people are doing that strict of a check. :)

Comment: For what it's worth, the answer provided about using `.closest` is a better answer at this point to the question asked here.

Answer (score 118):

In jQuery 1.6, you can use the following code generically, e.g. targetElt and parentElt can both be DOM elements or jQuery-wrapped objects, as well as selectors:

```
$(targetElt).closest(parentElt).length > 0
```

Some of the other answers require you to refer to elements by their IDs, which isn't useful if all you have is a DOM element without an ID. Also, if you want to make sure that the targetElt is a strict descendant of parentElt (in other words, you don't want to count parentElt as its own descendant), make sure to add a `targetElt != parentElt` check before your call to `.closest()`, or use `.parents().find()` as Jonathan Sampson suggests.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. All the other answers in this question and the dup require knowing ID's / classes. This one is perfectly transparent to all of that

Comment: 0 is falsey so you can simply use $(targetElt).closest(parentElt).length as a condition. (ie without checking length is > 0)

Answer (score 51):

### JQuery

With jQuery >=1.4 (2010) you can use the very fast function [jQuery.contains()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.contains/)

This static method works with DOM elements, not with jQuery elements and returns `true` or `false`.

```
jQuery.contains( container, descendant )
```

Example: To check if a element is in the document you could do this:

```
jQuery.contains( document.body, myElement )
```

### Native DOM

There is also a native DOM method [Node.contains()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.contains) that all browsers since ie5+ supports. So you can do it without jQuery:

```
document.body.contains( myElement )
```

Comment: You can use jQuery objects by pulling the DOM element from the object by adding "[0]" -> https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-pull-a-native-dom-element-from-a-jquery-object/

Comment: This is the best answer, it doesn’t rely on the elements having unique selectors and—more importantly—it gives a non jquery solution.

Answer (score 21):

How about

```
$("#homo-herectus").parents().is("#australopithecus");
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `is()` function like so:

```
alert($('#homo-sapiens').is('#australopithecus *'));
// -> true

alert($('#homo-herectus').is('#homo-sapiens *'));
// -> false
```

Comment: Don't you think using * (asterix) is too expensive as it check all children without stoping on first match?

Answer (score 4):

```
$.fn.descendantOf = function(element) {
    element = $(element)[0];
    var current = this;
    var body    = document.body;
    while (current && current != element && current != document.body) {
        current = $(current).parent()[0];
    }
    if (typeof(current) == "undefined" || typeof(current) == "null") {
        return false;
    } else if (current == element) {
        return true;
    } else if (current == document.body) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Example:

```
<div id="foo">
    <div id="bar">
        <div id="baz"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And:

```
$('#foo').descendantOf('#bar');  // false
$('#foo').descendantOf('#foo');  // false
$('#foo').descendantOf(document.body);  // true
$('#bar').descendantOf('#foo');  // true
$('#baz').descendantOf('#foo');  // true
```

Comment: `typeof` is not a function, it's a keyword. You don't need the parentheses, although it's still valid. `typeof current == "undefined"`

Answer (score 3):

You could attempt to `.find()` it in the Elements `.children()`

```
$("#lucy").find("#homo-erectus").length;
```

Or the opposite direction:

```
$("#homo-erectus").parents().find("#lucy").length;
```

Comment: I don't know the jQuery syntax, but it would be quicker to check the parents() of the descendant item, rather than all the children of the ancestor, right?

Comment: @harpo, Potentially. Depending on users particular DOM. Good advice though - definitely something to consider.

Answer (score 2):

Best method that I found is using Dan G. Switzer, II's method found here:
http://blog.pengoworks.com/index.cfm/2008/9/24/Using-jQuery-to-determine-if-an-element-is-a-child-of-another-element

```
jQuery.fn.isChildOf = function(b){ 
    return (this.parents(b).length > 0); 
};
```

Then you would just use the plugin as:

```
$('homo-sapiens').isChildOf('australopithecus');
// -> true

$('homo-herectus').isChildOf('homo-sapiens');
// -> false
```

Comment: This only determines a single level of descendance

Comment: @MildFuzz I'm pretty sure you're wrong about that. `parents()` traverses all the way up the tree to look for a match. https://api.jquery.com/parents/

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to closest() that uses (almost) the same traverse principle and doesn't include the element itself: `child.parentsUntil(ancestor).last().parent().is(ancestor)`.

```
var child = $('#homo-sapiens');
var ancestor = $('#australopithecus');

console.log(child.parentsUntil(ancestor).last().parent().is(ancestor)); // true
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function descendantOf(parentId, childId) {
   return ( $('#'+parentId+' > #'+childId).length === 1 );
}
```

That should work.

As was pointed out in the comment below, if you don't want it to be just direct descendants:

```
function descendantOf(parentId, childId) {
   return ( $('#'+childId, $('#'+parentId)).length === 1 );
}
```

Comment: The use of the > character in the selector will limit the check to only first-generation decdendants.  If you want to check to see if its any kind of descendant (as opposed to direct descendant) then simply remove the > character.

Answer (score -1):

Supposing to rewrite your initial statement in:

```
$('#homo-sapiens').descendantOf('#australopithecus');
```

try to plugin:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.descendantOf = function(parentId) {
        return this.closest(parentId).length != 0;
    }
})(jQuery)
```