# Check if div is descendant of another

Tags: javascript

[Best way to find out if element is a descendant of another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1059459/best-way-to-find-out-if-element-is-a-descendant-of-another) there is another question, very similiar to this one but its jquery.

so, how do I do it in js ? 
I have divs a, b, c, d nested in this order.
also, not sure if matters, there is another a, b, c... and another. its not just a single element. there is many by same id/class.

so I want to see if d has a parent(no matter how deep it is nested, as long as there is some parent on top its ok) called a.

edit:
also, I had this idea that I could check childnodes of "a" and see if "d" is one of them, but couldnt implement it. if someone can get it working, itd be awesome.

Comment: "`there is many by same id`" There should not be, `id`s must be unique within the same DOM.

Comment: I used them as classes, I know its wrong but its just a semantics problem. I can change all of them to classes withn seconds anyway.

Comment: Maybe this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.contains ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
// x is the element we are checking
while (x = x.parentNode) { 
    if (x.id == "a") console.log("FOUND");
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Didn't know about the [parentElement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8685739/difference-between-dom-parentnode-and-parentelement#8685780). +1

Comment: You should use parentNode instead of parentElement. parentElement is an old Internet Explorer thing that is no longer supported.

Comment: better to use `node.contains` (see answer below)

Comment: @mb21 It is not checking deeply.

Comment: @atilkan from MDN: "indicating whether a node is a descendant of a given node, i.e. the node itself, one of its direct children (childNodes), one of the children's direct children, and so on."

Comment: @mb21 It says direct children. Not if children's children or grandchild.

Comment: @atilkan I just tried it and node.contains will check deeply. a > b > c a.contains(c) is true.

Comment: @mb21 Can you share the example, please?

Comment: @BrianK You're thinking of the old (**old!**) `parentElement` property from IE5 (1999) whereas [the modern `parentElement` has been part of the W3C/WHATWG standard DOM since around 2008](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentElement)

Answer (score 122):

You can use `node.contains` to check if a node contains another node.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.contains

Answer (score 45):

If you want to use pure javascript use `node.contains`.

e.g.

```
var a = document.getElementById('a');
var d = document.getElementById('d')
if (a.contains(d)) {
    alert('d is a descendant of a');
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FlameTrap/pwVPC/

Comment: But this needs for the elements to be identified by 'id' - not by class.

Comment: @PedroFerreira you sure? It seems to be working with the elements that don't have any IDs as well.

Comment: @The Sexiest Man in Jamaica: so how do you identify them?
By class...(getElementsByClassName) ? Doesn't work.

Comment: @PedroFerreira I'm comparing an `onClick` target element with a `getElementsByTagName` array in a loop. It actually worked so I guess JavaScript has a way to identify elements without relying on classes and IDs.

Comment: @The Sexiest Man in Jamaica that's right. What I was refering to is getting elements by CLASS - not unique.

Comment: @PedroFerreira This question isn't about how to get elements, just to check if one is a descendant of the other. The example code in this answer is just to show you what to do *after* you have gotten references to two elements. Feel free to use any method you like to get the references. `document.querySelectorAll`, or `getElementsById` or `getElementsByTagName`, or anything you like!

Comment: @ErikE: I'm not talking about the question. This answer IS getting (unique) elements.

Answer (score 8):

The method `closest()` might also be useful in such cases. This method returns the closest ancestor element of an element that matches a given selector (e.g. a class or id). If there is no such element, the method returns `null`.

```
let d = document.getElementById("d");
// if there is no ancestor with the id 'a', the method returns null and this evaluates to false:
if(d.closest("#a")){
   alert("d is a descendant of an element with the id 'a'");
}
```

You can find further description and more usage examples on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest).

Answer (score -1):

> edit: also, I had this idea that I could check childnodes of "a" and see if "d" is one of them, but couldnt implement it. if someone can get it working, itd be awesome.

For each ancestor, call querySelector, querySelectorAll, getElementsByClassName and so on.

```
let ancestors = document.querySelectorAll('ancestor a');
for(let i = 0; i < ancestors.length; i++){
    let a = ancestors[i];
    if(a.querySelector('descendant d')) {
        console.log(a);
    }
}
```

Or

```
let ancestors = document.querySelectorAll('ancestor a');
for(let i = 0; i < ancestors.length; i++){
    let a = ancestors[i];
    let descendants = a.querySelectorAll('descendant d');
    if(descendants.length > 0) {
        console.log(a);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is another one. Oh this is the old-fashioned way. It works but do not use. Use the [`contains()` method of html nodes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/contains) instead.

```js
function isDescendentOf(element, parent) {
  while (element) {
    if (element === parent) {
      return true;
    }
    element = element.parentElement;
  }
  return false;
}
```