# JavaScript check if element is child

Tags: javascript, html, parent-child

How can I check using JavaScript, if an HTML element is a child of a particular `<div>` element?

```
if (divElement == child){
   // do something...
}
```

EDIT: Thank you for the answers. I also had a similair question about descendants and found the answer here [Check if div is descendant of another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17773852/check-if-div-is-descendant-of-another)

Comment: `element.parentNode === divElement` ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/contains

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code may help you determine whether the two elements of parent-child relationships.

```
function isChild (obj,parentObj){
    while (obj != undefined && obj != null && obj.tagName.toUpperCase() != 'BODY'){
        if (obj == parentObj){
            return true;
        }
        obj = obj.parentNode;
    }
    return false;
}
```

then use the result of `isChild` call as condition `if` statement.

```
if(isChild(child,divElement)){
    // doSomething...
}
```

Comment: I believe this is the proper way of doing it, thanks

Comment: doesn't this return true for the 2 same object..?  isChild(child, child) = true ?

Answer (score 5):

you can check either starting from parent element, or child element.

1- check if current element is inside the parent element
`parentEl.contains(el)`

or

2- current element's parent is the parentElement we have stored
`el.parentNode === parentEl`

Answer (score 3):

```
if (element.parentNode == divElement) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

use [contains](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/contains) function of Node - `divElement.contains(child)` 
 or this function in case contains does not exists.

```
function contains(first, second) {
    var adown = first.nodeType === 9 ? first.documentElement : first;

    if (first === second) {
        return true;
    }

    if (adown.contains) { 
        return adown.contains(second);
    }

    return first.compareDocumentPosition && first.compareDocumentPosition(second) & 16);
}
```

in case you need to return false when the nodes are the same

```
function notContains(first, second) {
    var adown = first.nodeType === 9 ? first.documentElement : first;

    if (first === second) {
        return false;
    }

    if (adown.contains) { 
        return !adown.contains(second);
    }

    return first.compareDocumentPosition && first.compareDocumentPosition(second) & 16) !== 16;
}
```

Comment: That will also return true if they are the same node.

Answer (score -1):

Use nodeName to check

```
if(elementObj.parentElement.nodeName == "DIV"){
//Your Code
}
```